# How can I find functions containing direct memory access in a device driver?

Tags: embedded, source

In a given Linux distribution's source code, how can I track down the files and functions that directly access memory registers for peripherals?

I'm doing embedded development on several different platforms. With the Raspberry Pi, I was able to find plenty of guides on direct memory access and I was pleased to find that its BCM2835 system on a chip has an easy to understand [datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf). However, I suspect that somewhere in the files on my Pi or somewhere online I can find the source code that is used by the packaged device drivers to do the direct memory access.

Someone explained their search for the source of a GPIO debouncing function in [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55283/why-isnt-gpio-set-debounce-working-in-my-raspberry-pi-zero-kernel-module/55284#55284). In the case of that function, it did not appear to be implemented on the Raspberry Pi. What if, though, I wanted to find the function used by the GPIO driver on the Pi that directly accesses memory to set a pin as an output and write high or low to it? How would I track down the function that is used on the Intel Edison in it's Yocto Linux distribution? How would I track down functions used by the element14 Warp7?

Comment: I don't think there's a "generic" way, you usually just read the driver source and understand what it does. Many drivers have a header file where they declare #define's etc. for the register addresses, so once you found these, it's just an easy `grep` away. And once you understood which internal variables hold the base address of the register space, finding other register accesses is also easy.

Comment: Can you please walk me through an example? Should I look through the Pi's file system or should I look online? I'm guessing online, since I can only seem to find the .ko compiled module files on the Pi. I went to the [gpio folder](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/) on the Linux Cross Reference site, but there is no file for the BCM2835, which is the Pi's system on a chip.

Comment: for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)